# How to get best concurrency performance while using KafkaProducer?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

[KafkaProducer javadoc](https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/1.1.0/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) says that using single instance will give faster performance than using multiple instances "*The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances.*" - what is the explanation for this?

On the contrary while going through [KafkaProducer.send() code flow](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/8250738ae41f6f0a87dc1e21e7623c5d69cae148/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/RecordAccumulator.java#L196) found out that there is a sychronized block on TopicPartition object, so we should be able achieve better performance if we are using multiple producer instances...?

Please advise on the recommended approach to achieve best performance with KafkaProducer.

Comment: docs is already giving you a very clear and useful performance advice. Probably single instance is better because that increases the scope of batching, which reduces both the messaging overhead and the latency.

Comment: Thanks Gagan. This helps...